# Bulls & Cows C# Implementation (Mastermind Variation)

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence

Bulls & Cows is a game for two players in which each one has a secret number with 4 non-repeating digits, and each one tries to guess the other number.

For instance, let´s say my secret number is 1576.

If my opponent says the number 1234, i would answer: 1F, because the digit 1 is in my secret number and in the same position.
If my opponent says the number 7890, i would answer: 1P, because the digit 7 is in my secret number and in different position.
ETC.
[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows) it is explained.

Well, as a hobby, I wish to implement a computer player that tryes to guess my number, but I don't know where to start,

- any ideas?
- Is there something already done on this game?
- Is out there any C# Implementation?

Comment: Oddly enough, I wrote something almost exactly like this when I first started messing around with LINQ... I can post all the code once I find it if you wish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variant of the game [Mastermind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Algorithms). Quite a lot of work has been done on algorithms for guessing solutions. Beyond those shown at the wikipedia link, some googling using "mastermind" as the keyword will probably turn up a lot. (I'm assuming you haven't found much so far because you didn't know that name).

Comment: I didn't know the name of the game, the game I described is called "picas y fijas" in spanish.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a variation on the game 'Mastermind' - there are a few resources [here](http://richardbowles.tripod.com/durham/ai/mastermind/mastermind.html) and [here](http://ece.uprm.edu/~s016965/ICOM%205015%20-%20Artificial%20Intelligence/Mastermind%20Report.doc) (.doc), as well as on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Algorithms).

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a MasterMind variant.

Answer (score 0):

You're playing a variation of the board game "Mastermind".  See the algorithm section of the wikipedia article:

[`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game))

Answer (score 0):

This is a linux flavor of the game, I'm pretty sure you can get source for it and port it to C#

http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=182681&package_id=211908

have fun..

Comment: That program allows to generate a number for user guessing, not the other way around, but thanks anyway